# How do I serve a fast ball in Wii Sports?

Tags: nintendo-wii, wii-sports

I recently [replaced our damaged Wii Sports disc](http://store.nintendo.com/webapp/wcs/stores/servlet/ProductDisplay?productId=159708&currency=USD&catalogId=10001&tranId=0&lastAction=setCurr&storeId=10001&languageId=-1&categoryId=60707&ddkey=http:SetCurrencyPreference) after a year or so of it being out of commission.  My son and I have been having a lot of fun playing together.

When we play tennis, **I'm getting vague recollections of being able to serve an extremely fast ball, but it's been long enough since I've played that I can't remember the technique**.  How can I increase the speed of my serves?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To create a fast served ball (the one that's on fire), you have to hit the ball when it's at its peak. I don't have a specific strategy to do so, but that's how you do it.

Comment: This is correct.  It takes some practice to get the timing right consistently.  You are basically hitting the ball when it's stopped moving up (and before it's started falling down).

Comment: Guess I was just lucky then :p

Answer (score 2):

It has a lot to do with timing.  I like to use a flick of the wrist downward when the ball is at its peak.  Takes some practice but once you've got it down you will have no problem doing it every time.

Answer (score 1):

I have the strategy: the ball is at it's peak when the ball is tangent to the net according to your view (just touching) just throw it up a few times and see that the ball just makes contact with the bottom of the net from your view. Hope this helps

Answer (score -1):

It's been a little while for me, too - but I'm pretty sure that the best way to get a fast serve is to swing from over your head in a fast and short downward swing... seemed to work out fairly well for me.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the [regular Wii Remote](http://u.tknet.nl/goiqMU) does not have the motion tracking capabilities needed for such things to be detected.

Comment: The link you provide says _"The Wii Remote has the ability to sense acceleration along three axes"_ - that really is all you need...

Comment: No. In this case you would also need positional data, to determine what angle the Wii Remote is being held at. I'm getting quite consistent fast serves by merely flicking my wrist at the right moment.

Comment: Table tennis on Wii Sports Resort with the [MotionPlus](http://u.tknet.nl/dL23Z9) is probably a good example of this, although I cannot confirm this myself.

Comment: I don't know why it needs to know the position to detect a fast short downward swing - but since this answer is obviously not the right one, I don't think it really matters.

Comment: Downward relative to what? If you were, for example, to hold the Wii Remote upside down, it could be described as an upward swing.